# How is SSH_AUTH_SOCK setup and used by ssh-agent?

Tags: sockets, ssh, public-key-encryption, ssh-agent

I have been able to setup the sharing of ssh-agent for public-key authentication after reading https://superuser.com/a/230872/301446

The environment file thus generated has the following contents:

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-OwqeSuxmEsQN/agent.4744; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=8960; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
#echo Agent pid 8960;
```

And `agent.4744` has:

```
!<socket >24194 s 07DF88C6-E9997283-4C471010-2FE57D77
```

Would you know how this socket is used by ssh-agent? I can understand that it's used by ssh-agent to share authentication information but exactly how?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

From [here](http://blog.joncairns.com/2013/12/understanding-ssh-agent-and-ssh-add/):

> $SSH_AUTH_SOCK contains the path of the unix file socket that the
>   agent uses for communication with other processes. This is essential
>   for ssh-add.

Comment: Broken link, now here - http://blog.joncairns.com/2013/12/understanding-ssh-agent-and-ssh-add/

Comment: That blog post helped me a lot to understand the real problem. Highly recommended

Comment: both links now broken

Comment: tnx, I forgot to make `ssh-add`

Comment: @balupton works for me: http://blog.joncairns.com/2013/12/understanding-ssh-agent-and-ssh-add

Comment: I would argue the method depicted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390631) is better than the one suggested in joncairns blog